# Android Studio is removing Shelf contents

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Every time I restart Android Studio it completely removes all changes I have Shelved. When I go to Version Control the Shelf tab is gone and the entire "shelf" directory is gone from `<Project Name>/shelf` location.  This is happening for all of my projects.

I'm using macOS 10.13.6 and Android Studio 3.1.2

Does anyone know why this is happening and if/how I can restore the contents of the shelf directory?

Comment: Sounds a little similar to this issue, though I haven't personally experienced it in a long time: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155955

It might be worth searching for, and potentially filing a bug report on the official tracker for your particular issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using Local History to restore the Shelf contents. Unless the `.idea` folder is marked as excluded, it should work.

To find out why it happens logs and some additional info is needed, please submit a request with logs files attached to the [tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)